# Custom excerpt_more filter not working when <!--more--> tag is present

Tags: filters, excerpt

I'm doing this inside Thesis 2, in case that matters.

I am using `the_excerpt();` on my blog page to get the posts.  And I'm using two custom filters:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    if (is_page(5)){
    return 19;
    } else{
    return 120; 
    }
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">more</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

The custom excerpt_more runs correctly unless there is a `<!--more-->` tag in the post.  In that case, it displays the post up to that point, rather than the 120 word length set above (which is what I like) BUT... it doesn't display the custom excerpt_more and I don't know why.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the_excerpt(), do you still need to use the <!--more--> tag in your posts?

Comment: This is for a client and they already have many posts some with and without more, and I like the control it gives them, but this just gave me an idea, going to check...

Comment: Backup your MySQl DB, and then run a query to find and replace the more tag with nothing.

Comment: My idea manually filling in the excerpt box, and removing the more doesn't work either.

Comment: @gdaniel,  Removing the more tags isn't my issue. I want the client to have control over whether they want the 120 word automatic excerpt *or* their own, more-tag-controlled excerpt.  The problem is that when the excerpt is their's the custom 'excerpt_more' does not appear.

Comment: I understand your problem. But it looks like WP was designed that way. It uses the more tag if finds it, or it falls back to excerpt if it's there. These functions are defined in wp-includes/post_template.php. Take a look and you can see that it first checks to see if the more tag is present. And no, I do not know a way to overwrite this right now. Sorry I was not much help.

Comment: Annoying. I couldn't decipher the php enough to attempt modifying it.  I've had to resort to removing my filter, creating a custom 'read more' in the template and using jQuery to move it where I want it. Ug. Thank you anyway.